# Obj-C, Need help with game architecture

Tags: objective-c, architecture, 2d

Hey, basically i'm on my second App for the iPhone SDK and im really enjoying myself.
Im currently creating a 'raidan' style 2d game, where the user flys a character upward and encounters enemies that shoot bullets etc.

The game is coming along well, I have bullets firing, enemies moving (basic), collecting coins and a fuel/shield system, but i'm starting to become abit overwhelmed with the amount of code and i'm wondering if theres a more 'efficient' way to do this.

I have no layers but for the main layer, for example the HUD is on the same layer as the enemies etc.
If you would use multiple layers, can RectIntersectRect work between layers?

I have also failed to incorporate custom classes, I'm using NSMutableArray's to put all my objects in.

I suppose this is all abit ambiguous. 
How would design the architecture for a 2d flight game with multiple levels?
Please understand that I have no clue - I simply started writing methods upon methods upon methods.

Between each level - Would you duplicate methods (physics, UIImageView creation etc)?

Thanks for your thought & time

Comment: I think it's hard to answer this sensibly in the scope of an answer here. You might want to consider reading a good book on game design first, maybe from e.g. [this questions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/497/good-game-design-books) on gamedev? Still, one point: Never ever duplicate code if you can parameterize it. Levels should only be described by data and use functionality provided by common code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Georg is right, it’s not easy to give a simple answer to your problems. I would suggest that you spend some time reading the [Cocos 2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) source code. You will learn some basic tricks that you should do to keep the code manageable. All in all it’s a good idea to use some existing game framework if you are starting. It will keep you from reinventing the wheel and cut down on the design choices.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using Cocos2D, but im unsure if I can import my work into the framework hassle free, so i've been hesitant.

Comment: @Oliver: When starting on programming it's quite normal to rewrite programs once you figure out how the design can be improved. Fixing something that isn't suited for the task at hand is usually much more painful.

Comment: I've decided to take the plunge and get started on the Cocos2D framework. Your absolutely right, it does provide a solid architecture. Thanks for your advice!